# JavaScript: How to find out width and height of viewpoint in browser window?

Tags: javascript

How to find out width and height of viewpoint in browser window? And How to find out how much document scrolled to down and to right?

Comment: And How to find out how much document scrolled to down and to right?

Comment: Try reading any one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions-with-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817446/good-way-to-estimate-available-browser-area

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this function... and call it when needed :)

```
function getViewPortSize()
{
    var viewportwidth;
    var viewportheight;

    //Standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7)
    if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
    {
        viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
        viewportheight = window.innerHeight
    }

    // IE6
    else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
    && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
    'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
    {
        viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
    }

    //Older IE
    else
    {
        viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
        viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
    }

    return viewportwidth + "~" + viewportheight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height = document.body.clientHeight;
width = document.body.clientWidth;
```

regarding scroll position, I'm not sure if there is a standard way of determining that, however this should work in most browsers:

```
scrolled = document.body.scrollTop;
```